# TagCloud size problem

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, linq-to-sql

I am using code to display a tag cloud based on percentage values. The first time a tag is added to my db, it appears large, and then shrinks relative to other tags (the more times they're added). Here is the code:

```
private void BindTagCloud()
{

    int pro_id = Convert.ToInt32(proj_id);
    int iteration_id = Convert.ToInt32(iteration);

    var tagSummaryNegative = from af in db.AgileFactors
                     join psf in db.ProjectStoryFactors on af.AgileFactorID equals psf.AgileFactorID
                     join s in db.Stories on psf.StoryID equals s.StoryID
                     join pim in db.ProjectIterationMembers on s.ProjectIterationMemberID equals pim.ProjectIterationMemberID
                     join it in db.Iterations on pim.ProjectIterationID equals it.ProjectIterationID
                     join pro in db.Projects on it.ProjectID equals pro.ProjectID
                     where pro.ProjectID == pro_id &&
                           pro.ProjectID == it.ProjectID &&
                           it.ProjectIterationID == pim.ProjectIterationID &&
                           pim.ProjectIterationMemberID == s.ProjectIterationMemberID && s.StoryCategoryID == 1 &&
                           s.StoryID == psf.StoryID &&
                           psf.AgileFactorID == af.AgileFactorID
                     group af by af.Name into tagGroup

                     select new
                     {

                         Tag = tagGroup.Key,
                         tagCount = tagGroup.Count()

                     };

    var tagSummaryNegativeIteration = from af in db.AgileFactors
                             join psf in db.ProjectStoryFactors on af.AgileFactorID equals psf.AgileFactorID
                             join s in db.Stories on psf.StoryID equals s.StoryID
                             join pim in db.ProjectIterationMembers on s.ProjectIterationMemberID equals pim.ProjectIterationMemberID
                             join it in db.Iterations on pim.ProjectIterationID equals it.ProjectIterationID
                             join pro in db.Projects on it.ProjectID equals pro.ProjectID
                             where pro.ProjectID == pro_id &&
                                   pro.ProjectID == it.ProjectID &&
                                   it.ProjectIterationID == iteration_id &&
                                   it.ProjectIterationID == pim.ProjectIterationID &&
                                   pim.ProjectIterationMemberID == s.ProjectIterationMemberID && s.StoryCategoryID == 1 &&
                                   s.StoryID == psf.StoryID &&
                                   psf.AgileFactorID == af.AgileFactorID
                             group af by af.Name into tagGroup

                             select new
                             {

                                 Tag = tagGroup.Key,
                                 tagCount = tagGroup.Count()

                             };

    var tagSummaryPositive = from af in db.AgileFactors
                             join psf in db.ProjectStoryFactors on af.AgileFactorID equals psf.AgileFactorID
                             join s in db.Stories on psf.StoryID equals s.StoryID
                             join pim in db.ProjectIterationMembers on s.ProjectIterationMemberID equals pim.ProjectIterationMemberID
                             join it in db.Iterations on pim.ProjectIterationID equals it.ProjectIterationID
                             join pro in db.Projects on it.ProjectID equals pro.ProjectID
                             where pro.ProjectID == pro_id &&
                                   pro.ProjectID == it.ProjectID &&
                                   it.ProjectIterationID == pim.ProjectIterationID &&
                                   pim.ProjectIterationMemberID == s.ProjectIterationMemberID && s.StoryCategoryID == 0 &&
                                   s.StoryID == psf.StoryID &&
                                   psf.AgileFactorID == af.AgileFactorID
                             group af by af.Name into tagGroup

                             select new
                             {

                                 Tag = tagGroup.Key,
                                 tagCount = tagGroup.Count()

                             };

    var tagSummaryPositiveIteration = from af in db.AgileFactors
                             join psf in db.ProjectStoryFactors on af.AgileFactorID equals psf.AgileFactorID
                             join s in db.Stories on psf.StoryID equals s.StoryID
                             join pim in db.ProjectIterationMembers on s.ProjectIterationMemberID equals pim.ProjectIterationMemberID
                             join it in db.Iterations on pim.ProjectIterationID equals it.ProjectIterationID
                             join pro in db.Projects on it.ProjectID equals pro.ProjectID
                             where pro.ProjectID == pro_id &&
                                   pro.ProjectID == it.ProjectID &&
                                   it.ProjectIterationID == iteration_id &&
                                   it.ProjectIterationID == pim.ProjectIterationID &&
                                   pim.ProjectIterationMemberID == s.ProjectIterationMemberID && s.StoryCategoryID == 0 &&
                                   s.StoryID == psf.StoryID &&
                                   psf.AgileFactorID == af.AgileFactorID
                             group af by af.Name into tagGroup

                             select new
                             {

                                 Tag = tagGroup.Key,
                                 tagCount = tagGroup.Count()

                             };


    int maxTagFrequencyNegative = (from t in tagSummaryNegative select (int?)t.tagCount).Max() ?? 0;
    int maxTagFrequencyPositive = (from t in tagSummaryPositive select (int?)t.tagCount).Max() ?? 0;

    int maxTagFrequencyNegativeIteration = (from t in tagSummaryNegativeIteration select (int?)t.tagCount).Max() ?? 0;
    int maxTagFrequencyPositiveIteration = (from t in tagSummaryPositiveIteration select (int?)t.tagCount).Max() ?? 0;


    var tagCloudNegative = from af in db.AgileFactors
                   join psf in db.ProjectStoryFactors on af.AgileFactorID equals psf.AgileFactorID
                   join s in db.Stories on psf.StoryID equals s.StoryID
                   join pim in db.ProjectIterationMembers on s.ProjectIterationMemberID equals pim.ProjectIterationMemberID
                   join it in db.Iterations on pim.ProjectIterationID equals it.ProjectIterationID
                   join pro in db.Projects on it.ProjectID equals pro.ProjectID
                   where pro.ProjectID == pro_id &&
                         pro.ProjectID == it.ProjectID &&
                         it.ProjectIterationID == pim.ProjectIterationID &&
                         pim.ProjectIterationMemberID == s.ProjectIterationMemberID && s.StoryCategoryID == 1 &&
                         s.StoryID == psf.StoryID &&
                         psf.AgileFactorID == af.AgileFactorID
                   group af by af.Name into tagGroup
                   select new
                   {

                       Tag = tagGroup.Key,
                       weight = (double)tagGroup.Count() / maxTagFrequencyNegative * 100
                   };

    var tagCloudNegativeIteration = from af in db.AgileFactors
                           join psf in db.ProjectStoryFactors on af.AgileFactorID equals psf.AgileFactorID
                           join s in db.Stories on psf.StoryID equals s.StoryID
                           join pim in db.ProjectIterationMembers on s.ProjectIterationMemberID equals pim.ProjectIterationMemberID
                           join it in db.Iterations on pim.ProjectIterationID equals it.ProjectIterationID
                           join pro in db.Projects on it.ProjectID equals pro.ProjectID
                           where pro.ProjectID == pro_id &&
                                 pro.ProjectID == it.ProjectID &&
                                 it.ProjectIterationID == iteration_id &&
                                 it.ProjectIterationID == pim.ProjectIterationID &&
                                 pim.ProjectIterationMemberID == s.ProjectIterationMemberID && s.StoryCategoryID == 1 &&
                                 s.StoryID == psf.StoryID &&
                                 psf.AgileFactorID == af.AgileFactorID
                           group af by af.Name into tagGroup
                           select new
                           {

                               Tag = tagGroup.Key,
                               weight = (double)tagGroup.Count() / maxTagFrequencyNegativeIteration * 100
                           };

    var tagCloudPositive = from af in db.AgileFactors
                           join psf in db.ProjectStoryFactors on af.AgileFactorID equals psf.AgileFactorID
                           join s in db.Stories on psf.StoryID equals s.StoryID
                           join pim in db.ProjectIterationMembers on s.ProjectIterationMemberID equals pim.ProjectIterationMemberID
                           join it in db.Iterations on pim.ProjectIterationID equals it.ProjectIterationID
                           join pro in db.Projects on it.ProjectID equals pro.ProjectID
                           where pro.ProjectID == pro_id &&
                                 pro.ProjectID == it.ProjectID &&
                                 it.ProjectIterationID == pim.ProjectIterationID &&
                                 pim.ProjectIterationMemberID == s.ProjectIterationMemberID && s.StoryCategoryID == 0 &&
                                 s.StoryID == psf.StoryID &&
                                 psf.AgileFactorID == af.AgileFactorID
                           group af by af.Name into tagGroup
                           select new
                           {

                               Tag = tagGroup.Key,
                               weight = (double)tagGroup.Count() / maxTagFrequencyPositive * 100
                           };

    var tagCloudPositiveIteration = from af in db.AgileFactors
                                    join psf in db.ProjectStoryFactors on af.AgileFactorID equals psf.AgileFactorID
                                    join s in db.Stories on psf.StoryID equals s.StoryID
                                    join pim in db.ProjectIterationMembers on s.ProjectIterationMemberID equals pim.ProjectIterationMemberID
                                    join it in db.Iterations on pim.ProjectIterationID equals it.ProjectIterationID
                                    join pro in db.Projects on it.ProjectID equals pro.ProjectID
                                    where pro.ProjectID == pro_id &&
                                          pro.ProjectID == it.ProjectID &&
                                          it.ProjectIterationID == iteration_id &&
                                          it.ProjectIterationID == pim.ProjectIterationID &&
                                          pim.ProjectIterationMemberID == s.ProjectIterationMemberID && s.StoryCategoryID == 0 &&
                                          s.StoryID == psf.StoryID &&
                                          psf.AgileFactorID == af.AgileFactorID
                                    group af by af.Name into tagGroup
                                    select new
                                    {

                                        Tag = tagGroup.Key,
                                        weight = (double)tagGroup.Count() / maxTagFrequencyPositiveIteration * 100
                                    };

    if (iteration_id != 0)
    {
        ListView1.DataSource = tagCloudNegativeIteration;
        ListView1.DataBind();

        ListView2.DataSource = tagCloudPositiveIteration;
        ListView2.DataBind();

    }
    else
    {
        ListView1.DataSource = tagCloudNegative;
        ListView1.DataBind();

        ListView2.DataSource = tagCloudPositive;
        ListView2.DataBind();

    }

}

public string GetTagSize(double weight)
{

    if (weight >= 99)
        return "xx-large";
    else if (weight >= 60)
        return "x-large";
    else if (weight >= 40)
        return "large";
    else if (weight >= 20)
        return "medium";
    else
        return "small";
}
```

What I would like to do, however, is make the tag small at first (the first time it's added), and then increase its size the more times it's mentioned. Does anyone know how I could do this? Many thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you have shown the tag should already appear small to begin with - tagGroup.Count() would be 1 and GetTagSize will return "small"

Something must be overriding this code to force the font size large - just take that out and I think you should get what you have asked for.

Comment: That's what I thought. I have updated my post to display my code. Can you see where the problem is? Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you take this:

```
weight = (((double)tagGroup.Count() / maxTagFrequencyNegative * 100) - 100) * -1
```

That way you take the largest numbers and reverse them.

Comment: I tried doing it this way. At first the tags appear small, but as I add more of them to my db, the ones that were added less times appear bigger than the ones occuring more often...

Answer (score 0):

I simplified your code to run it on my box. And everything seems to be OK. Here you can see my test page:

Test.aspx:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Test.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication2.Test" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>

    <style type="text/css">
        .xx-large
        {
            font-size: 30px;
        }

        .x-large
        {
            font-size: 25px;
        }

        .large
        {
            font-size: 20px;
        }

        .medium
        {
            font-size: 15px;
        }

        .small
        {
            font-size: 10px;
        }
        .tagCloud
        {
            padding: 20px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div class=tagCloud>
        <asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <span class='<%# GetTagSize((double)Eval("weight")) %>'>
                    <%# Eval("Tag") %></span>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:ListView>
    </div>
    <div class=tagCloud>
        <asp:ListView ID="ListView2" runat="server">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <span class='<%# GetTagSize((double)Eval("weight")) %>'>
                    <%# Eval("Tag") %></span>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:ListView>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Test.aspx.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace WebApplication2
{
    public partial class Test : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            BindTagCloud();
        }

        public class Race
        {
            public string GrandPrix { get; set; }
            public string TeamWinner { get; set; }
            public int Year { get; set; }
        }

        public IEnumerable<Race> GetRaces()
        {
            yield return new Race { GrandPrix = "Australia", TeamWinner = "Ferrari", Year = 2002 };
            yield return new Race { GrandPrix = "Malaysia", TeamWinner = "Williams-BMW", Year = 2002 };
            yield return new Race { GrandPrix = "Brazil", TeamWinner = "Ferrari", Year = 2002 };
            yield return new Race { GrandPrix = "San Marino", TeamWinner = "Ferrari", Year = 2002 };
            yield return new Race { GrandPrix = "Spain", TeamWinner = "Ferrari", Year = 2002 };
            yield return new Race { GrandPrix = "Austria", TeamWinner = "Ferrari", Year = 2002 };
            yield return new Race { GrandPrix = "Monaco", TeamWinner = "McLaren-Mercedes", Year = 2002 };
            yield return new Race { GrandPrix = "Canada", TeamWinner = "Ferrari", Year = 2002 };
            yield return new Race { GrandPrix = "Europe", TeamWinner = "Ferrari", Year = 2002 };
            yield return new Race { GrandPrix = "Great Britain", TeamWinner = "Ferrari", Year = 2002 };
            yield return new Race { GrandPrix = "France", TeamWinner = "Ferrari", Year = 2002 };
            yield return new Race { GrandPrix = "Germany", TeamWinner = "Ferrari", Year = 2002 };
            yield return new Race { GrandPrix = "Hungary", TeamWinner = "Ferrari", Year = 2002 };
            yield return new Race { GrandPrix = "Belgium", TeamWinner = "Ferrari", Year = 2002 };
            yield return new Race { GrandPrix = "Italy", TeamWinner = "Ferrari", Year = 2002 };
            yield return new Race { GrandPrix = "United States", TeamWinner = "Ferrari", Year = 2002 };
            yield return new Race { GrandPrix = "Japan", TeamWinner = "Ferrari", Year = 2002 };

            yield return new Race { GrandPrix = "Australia", TeamWinner = "McLaren-Mercedes", Year = 2003 };
            yield return new Race { GrandPrix = "Malaysia", TeamWinner = "McLaren-Mercedes", Year = 2003 };
            yield return new Race { GrandPrix = "Brazil", TeamWinner = "Jordan-Ford", Year = 2003 };
            yield return new Race { GrandPrix = "San Marino", TeamWinner = "Ferrari", Year = 2003 };
            yield return new Race { GrandPrix = "Spain", TeamWinner = "Ferrari", Year = 2003 };
            yield return new Race { GrandPrix = "Austria", TeamWinner = "Ferrari", Year = 2003 };
            yield return new Race { GrandPrix = "Monaco", TeamWinner = "Williams-BMW", Year = 2003 };
            yield return new Race { GrandPrix = "Canada", TeamWinner = "Ferrari", Year = 2003 };
            yield return new Race { GrandPrix = "Europe", TeamWinner = "Williams-BMW", Year = 2003 };
            yield return new Race { GrandPrix = "France", TeamWinner = "Williams-BMW", Year = 2003 };
            yield return new Race { GrandPrix = "Great Britain", TeamWinner = "Ferrari", Year = 2003 };
            yield return new Race { GrandPrix = "Germany", TeamWinner = "Williams-BMW", Year = 2003 };
            yield return new Race { GrandPrix = "Hungary", TeamWinner = "Renault", Year = 2003 };
            yield return new Race { GrandPrix = "Italy", TeamWinner = "Ferrari", Year = 2003 };
            yield return new Race { GrandPrix = "United States", TeamWinner = "Ferrari", Year = 2003 };
            yield return new Race { GrandPrix = "Japan", TeamWinner = "Ferrari", Year = 2003 };
        }

        private void BindTagCloud()
        {
            int year = 2002;

            var tagSummaryNegative = from t in GetRaces()
                                     where t.Year == 2002
                                     group t by t.TeamWinner into tagGroup
                                     select new
                                     {

                                         Tag = tagGroup.Key,
                                         tagCount = tagGroup.Count()

                                     };

            var tagSummaryNegativeIteration = from t in GetRaces()
                                              where t.Year == 2002
                                              group t by t.TeamWinner into tagGroup
                                              select new
                                              {

                                                  Tag = tagGroup.Key,
                                                  tagCount = tagGroup.Count()

                                              };

            var tagSummaryPositive = from t in GetRaces()
                                     where t.Year == 2003
                                     group t by t.TeamWinner into tagGroup
                                     select new
                                     {

                                         Tag = tagGroup.Key,
                                         tagCount = tagGroup.Count()

                                     };

            var tagSummaryPositiveIteration = from t in GetRaces()
                                              where t.Year == 2003
                                              group t by t.TeamWinner into tagGroup
                                              select new
                                              {

                                                  Tag = tagGroup.Key,
                                                  tagCount = tagGroup.Count()

                                              };


            int maxTagFrequencyNegative = (from t in tagSummaryNegative select (int?)t.tagCount).Max() ?? 0;
            int maxTagFrequencyPositive = (from t in tagSummaryPositive select (int?)t.tagCount).Max() ?? 0;

            int maxTagFrequencyNegativeIteration = (from t in tagSummaryNegativeIteration select (int?)t.tagCount).Max() ?? 0;
            int maxTagFrequencyPositiveIteration = (from t in tagSummaryPositiveIteration select (int?)t.tagCount).Max() ?? 0;


            var tagCloudNegative = from t in GetRaces()
                                   where t.Year == 2002
                                   group t by t.TeamWinner into tagGroup
                                   select new
                                   {

                                       Tag = tagGroup.Key,
                                       weight = (double)tagGroup.Count() / maxTagFrequencyNegative * 100
                                   };

            var tagCloudNegativeIteration = from t in GetRaces()
                                            where t.Year == 2002
                                            group t by t.TeamWinner into tagGroup
                                            select new
                                            {

                                                Tag = tagGroup.Key,
                                                weight = (double)tagGroup.Count() / maxTagFrequencyNegativeIteration * 100
                                            };

            var tagCloudPositive = from t in GetRaces()
                                   where t.Year == 2003
                                   group t by t.TeamWinner into tagGroup
                                   select new
                                   {

                                       Tag = tagGroup.Key,
                                       weight = (double)tagGroup.Count() / maxTagFrequencyPositive * 100
                                   };

            var tagCloudPositiveIteration = from t in GetRaces()
                                            where t.Year == 2003
                                            group t by t.TeamWinner into tagGroup
                                            select new
                                            {

                                                Tag = tagGroup.Key,
                                                weight = (double)tagGroup.Count() / maxTagFrequencyPositiveIteration * 100
                                            };

            if (year == 2002)
            {
                ListView1.DataSource = tagCloudNegativeIteration;
                ListView1.DataBind();

                ListView2.DataSource = tagCloudPositiveIteration;
                ListView2.DataBind();

            }
            else
            {
                ListView1.DataSource = tagCloudNegative;
                ListView1.DataBind();

                ListView2.DataSource = tagCloudPositive;
                ListView2.DataBind();

            }
        }

        public string GetTagSize(double weight)
        {

            if (weight >= 99)
                return "xx-large";
            else if (weight >= 60)
                return "x-large";
            else if (weight >= 40)
                return "large";
            else if (weight >= 20)
                return "medium";
            else
                return "small";
        }
    }
}
```

And here you can see result:
![Tag cloud][1]

I'd recommend to you to debug your code a bit and check if all numbers are correct. May be you have some problems in queries (incorrect join or something like that), because all other code works fine for me.

Hope this helps.

P.S. May be you have problem in css?