# Referencing variables from C# in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to use QueryStrings from my C# file in my ASPX file:

```
<asp:Button ID="LinkButtonDetails" runat="server" Text="DETAILS" 
PostBackUrl='<%# string.Format("~/projectdetails.aspx?guid=<%= id%>
&name=<%= name%>
&role=<%= company_role%>
&member=<%= mem_id%>
&company={0}
&project={1}&id={2}", Eval("CompanyID"), Eval("ProjectName"), Eval("ProjectID")) %>' />
```

The values are not appended to the url, what am I doing wrong? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that id, name, company_role, mem_id are fields or properties of your page(control) I'd recomend you to do following:

In aspx markup file write:

```
<asp:Button ID="LinkButtonDetails" runat="server" Text="DETAILS" PostBackUrl='<%# GenerateLink(Eval("CompanyID"), Eval("ProjectName"), Eval("ProjectID")) %>' />
```

And in the cs file write:

```
protected string GenerateLink(object companyId, object projectName, object projectId)
{
    return string.Format("~/projectdetails.aspx?guid={0}&name={1}&role={2}&member={3}&company={4}&project={5}&id={6}", id, name, company_role, mem_id, companyId, projectName, projectId);
}
```

Also don't forget to call DataBind.

P.S. You may also need to encode your query string arguments using HttpUtility.UrlEncode()

Comment: Thanks Oleg, that worked. I have a huge favour to ask you - would you mind looking at one of my other posts: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4917019/tagcloud-size-problem. I agree with paulash who thinks that something must be overriding my code to initially force the font size large. Can you see what the problem is? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

On page load call

```
Page.DataBind();
```